# Entity lambda, group by some columns and select more columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My logic went like this :

```
db.table.GroupBy(t => new { t.A, t.B}).Select( t => new { t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D});
```

At first, i thought `Distinct()` would help... but absolutely not.

See... i want to take only the different combinations of `A and B` but select `A, B, C, D`.

Comment: For the unique combinations of A and B which values of C and D do you want?  Like A1;B1;C1;D1 and A1;B1;C2;D2, would you want C1 and D1 or C2 and D2 or does it even matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the unique combination of `A` and `B` you just get them from the `Key` property, then you have to decide which `C` and `D` values you want.  Here I'm just pulling them from the first row for each `A` - `B` combination, but you can do other aggregations like `Min`, `Max`, or `Average`.

```
db.table.GroupBy(t => new {t.A, t.B})
    .Select(g => new {g.Key.A, g.Key.B, g.First().C, g.First().D});
```

The trick is to understand that `GroupBy` gives you a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TResult>>` and `IGrouping<TKey, TResult>` is an `IEnumerable<TResult>` and has a `Key` property of type `TKey`.  So the lambda you use in your `Select` is dealing with something that has a `Key` based on what you grouped on and is a collection of all the items/rows that are grouped for that unique key value.

Comment: Ha... I have to use an agregate, of course. What was i expecting... Don't even have to try it, this will work. Grouped iEnumerable, got it, it looks just like a dictionnary.